# C# WebBrowser background processing

Tags: c#, browser, desktop-application

I am working on c# .net framework, window application.
I just want to know, is there any way to process html document in background?
like I have a web browser control having html document written inside it asking for some fields of form.
I am able to change values of form but can I submit the form and process the next form which comes after submitting the previous form in background(i.e. I do not show the browser window to the user or show him whenever I want).
Is there any way?
Please help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# WebBrowser Control in a new thread.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/c-webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread)

Answer (score 1):

Just use WinForms and leave the browser out of it.